# Remove custom post type slug but keep related category taxonomy permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

struggling as well with custom url rewriting for custom post type taxonomies.

Here is my requirement:

domain/mycpt_category/postname/

It's well documented [here](http://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/) and in several SE threads removing the CPT basename so that the resulting permalink is:

domain/postname/

And I am able to construct the permalink such as:

domain/cpt-basename/cpt_category/postname ([following this solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/insert-category-of-taxonomy-between-custom-post-type-and-post) )

What I am really trying to achieve is removing the custom post type slug but keep its related taxonomy category so my link would be:

domain/mycpt_category/postname/

Thanks for you much appreciated help on this.

Answer (score 0):

When registering your custom post type have you tried to disable with_front in your rewrite array? For example, using an example for the post type book:

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' );
/**
 * Register a book post type.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
 */
function codex_book_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Books', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Book', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Books', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Book', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Books:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No books found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No books found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
                'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book', 'with_front' => false ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
```

However, the above example does not incorporate your rewrites mentioned so be sure to adjust your rewrite args to suit.

Comment: Hello Craig, thanks for your help, does the with_front tell wp to prepend the base before anything? So domain/base/cpt/ or domain/cpt ? I have though set it to false and I still get the base cpt in the url, to remove it I can add the code as available online to filter the link and remove the cpt base but I still get not working when I attempt to add the cpt related category.